# How to i combine the bones in my rig without them freaking out

Tags: modeling, bones

All the bones are separate and i want to fuse them so it can be easier to animate.

Everytime i tried to join them together they just freak out and don't want to pose anymore.

I'm a complete newbie to rigging and i don't know how to ask this question.  [image: pleasehelpidkwhatimdoing][image: distress]

Comment: Hello if it's an armature problem could you please share your armature?

Comment: I'd suggest you find some rigging tutorials online and start again!